# Is mentioning 'was laid off' necessary?

Tags: job-search, job-change

I have googled for this and [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6024/7978) question comes close. But most of the cases are either for fresh graduates or people who have worked for a few months or were on probation.

The scenario is a sr. software engineer with a decades experience, working his current job in the US for over 2 years has been asked to leave (due to corporate decisions). To facilitate in finding the next job the last working day for payroll would be 2/1. 
Wouldn't stating the obvious give this person the shorter end of compensation/deals? He already has had at least two companies offer lesser money (after verbally assuring more than what they are currently offering) when stated that he was let go. So in this case, how could this person best explain the reasons of why he is leaving his current job to his future employers ?

**Edit** : He has been asked not to report to work anymore. These two companies are consulting firms which act as staffing agencies for IT companies.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere They took down one or two from all teams. About 20 people (from a company of 200) were asked to go.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have edited the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how could this person best explain the reasons of why he is leaving
>   his current job to his future employers ?

When I interview candidates, I always ask "why did you leave?" If asked, the best explanation is always the truth.

In this case, before 2/1, he could answer something along the lines of "the company is downsizing and I wanted to get a jump on finding my next job".

After 2/1, a simple "I was laid off" is the truth, and is this the best way to explain the reason why he is leaving.

Particularly in recent times, there is little stigma left regarding people who have been laid off. It happens (happened to me twice) and hiring managers understand this.

Some will take advantage of this and respond with a lower offer, but many will not. Some hiring managers will assume that a laid-off candidate is desperate to get on a payroll, and thus will accept the lower offer. It sounds like this wasn't the case for your friend, as it sounds like he didn't accept the offer. But many won't respond with a lower offer (I don't when I see these circumstances).

Either way, being dishonest isn't a good way to start a new job. And if he gets caught in a less-than-honest response, he runs the risk of being branded a liar (and could even be dismissed for lying in the interview).

Comment: "the company is downsizing and I wanted to get a jump on finding my next job" - but this wont stand ground in case he gets his next job before 2/1 since the background verification process would reveal otherwise. No ?

Comment: @happybuddha - Their background check would be unable to determine if you lost the job to the company downsizing, you might still be reporting to work, but that period of time is actually normal.  If you say it was because of downsizing then unless they contact the company, who says otherwise, its still the truth.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about your future with your new job, you'd better mention that you are let go. You have decades of experience. You know you cannot keep this secret forever. It was *corporate decisions*. I suspect you are not the only one who is laid off. There are many ways your new employer will know about that sooner or later.

If you do not mention about the laid off, **your integrity will be in question** when your future employer finds out about it. It will hurt your future promotion opportunity or the job security in the worst case.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I agree. That was my mistake. I took out that part. I don't want to encourage anyone to lie.